# load an image using glide and use it in a different Image View without downloading it again

Tags: android

I have been searching for a way to do this or any method that will achieve desired outcome.

What I want to achieve is to load an image using glide and use it in a different Image View again without downloading it again from the serve (downloading would be the easier way but loading the image would take more time oviasly).

This is the relevant code:

```
           Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(getdetails.getRestlogo())
                .into(holder.ivlistrv);
        holder.ivlistrv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertlist_frag, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                ImageView alertiv = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alertiv);
                final RatingBar alertrb = (RatingBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alertrb);
                final TextView alerttv = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alerttv);
                //alertiv.set the image from ivlistrv
                alerttv.setText("Rate "+title);
                alertrb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)`

This will cache your image and next time it will be loaded from cache

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load(getdetails.getRestlogo())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.ivlistrv);
```

[Glide Chaching](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html)

Comment: i have been experimenting and this works fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use map for other ImageViews. Call the asyncTask class from mainActivity. I have tested this code and it works for me

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute("https://c.tribune.com.pk/2018/07/1759720-jinnahmazarkarachichangeofguardreutersxx-1531808403.jpg");
}
```

Download Image in 
**AsyncTask** class then stored it in Bitmap class variable which will hold it for you to use it wherever you want.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    Bitmap map;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            file = Glide.with(Main2Activity.this)
                    .load(strings[0])
                    .downloadOnly(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .get();

            map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: the glide receives url from an array of images what do u mean by use map for other images. will this save only one image?

Comment: It will hold bitmap for other images, for other images you don't need to download agian because map has stored the bitmap.

Comment: I have checked this code and It works for me. Let me breifly explain It for you. First you call async task which will download image for you once and the downloaded image will stored in map variable. So you can use map to set the Image in other Images, you don't have download it agian

Comment: i couldn't access the map variable from doInBackground and i couldn't set it to final so i went with the first answer

Comment: Dear, doInBackground return map which is bitmap and you can set it onPostExecute method. Anyway I posted it as a alternative answer. Maybe someone need it